# Java Decimal to binary using toBinaryString() method

Tags: java

I want to convert decimal number to binary, but this code doesn't work.

```
class DecimalToBinary{

public static void main(String a[]){
    System.out.println("Binary: ");
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryChar(200));
    System.out.println("\nBinary: ");
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryChar(500));
    System.out.println("\nBinary: ");
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryChar(3400));
    }
}
```

Comment: see the method in title and in code

Comment: "this code doesn't work" is *never* enough information. What *exactly* happens? Does it not compile? Throw an exception? Print the wrong results? What research have you done to try to overcome the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Integer.toBinaryString(200)` instead of `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryChar(200));`.

```
public class DecimalToBinary{

        public static void main(String a[]){
            System.out.println("Binary: ");
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(200));
            System.out.println("\nBinary: ");
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(500));
            System.out.println("\nBinary: ");
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(3400));
        }
}
```